# header('Content-Type: image/jpeg') turns page blank

Tags: php, html, image

I'm writing my first PHP code and I'm building a form in which the user uploads an image, the image is save in the directory and the name is saved in the database.
Than I have a page that displays that that data from the database i want it to show to image.

```
$imgdir = 'images/' . $result['fileName'];
$imgsrc = ImageCreateFromJpeg($imgdir);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($imgsrc);
```

the output i get is this(notice the block on top left)
[image]

but if remove header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); i got this output(whats in blue is the dir to the image i echoed to check if correct, and it is).

[image]

thanks!

Comment: @Daniel Doesn't matter, function names are case-insensitive.

Comment: You cannot write JPEG data inside Html. You need an Img tag to reference the image or a second script, that will send the image.

Comment: @lseni so what am i soppused to do? i want to display the image in black and white.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a simple html `img` tag, i guess, no need to overdo things :-)

`<img src="<?php echo 'images/' . $result['fileName'] ?>" alt="" />`

Comment: The thing is want to turn the picture grayscale later.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works properly. Are you sure that the image exists ? Can you add a `if( !file_exists( $imgdir ) ) { exit( 'file does not exists' ); }` just after `$imgdir = 'images/' . $result['fileName'];` ?

Comment: i get the same screen. i think the problem is with the header()